# Configuring erb directory in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

app/controllers/app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

app/views/index.erb

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory - .../app/controllers/views/index.erb
```

How do I configure erb to look into `app/views` instead of `app/controllers/views`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this by adjusting the configuration settings. Since you are using non-standard settings, you need to tell Sinatra what the actual root of your app is and where to find the views. At the top of your `app/controllers/app.rb` file add:

```
# sets root as the parent-directory of the current file
set :root, File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..')
# sets the view directory correctly
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "views") }
```

You can read more about Sinatra [configuration options](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) in the [Sinatra Documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/documentation).

Answer (score 3):

```
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "views") }
```

From http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__view_template_directory

Edit: Evidently that does nothing, heh. It would probably be best to have a file in `app/` that requires your controllers:

```
Dir.glob("controllers/*.rb").each { |r| require_relative r }
```

Then, `app/views` will be the default views directory.

Comment: This will fail because Sinatra sees the root directory as `app/controllers` and thus will look for the `views` directory under that path.